# How To Get Progressbar From Website With Jsoup?

Tags: android, jsoup

ı want to get progressbar information from a website to my android app. How can I do this?

Progressbar on website:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
          <div class="bar" id="prog" style="width: 0%;">  
   </div>
        </div>
```

How can I use this Website progressbar to Progressbar in my Android application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it will help you.

```
//String data = "<div class=\"progress progress-striped active\"> <div class=\"bar\" id=\"prog\" style=\"width: 56%;\"> </div> </div>";

//Document doc = Jsoup.parse(data);
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url").get();

String styleWidth = doc.select("div.progress.progress-striped.active div.bar").attr("style");

String progressText = styleWidth.substring(styleWidth.indexOf("width: ")+"width: ".length(), styleWidth.indexOf("%;"));

int progress = Integer.parseInt(progressText);    

ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);    
progressBar.setProgress(progress);
```

Comment: Thanks ^^ I'll try when  get home

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accepting it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark.)